# CSS for beginner to expert level

Tags: html, css

I am  not good enough in `CSS` coding though good hands on Web application development. I just wanted to understand the basic coding standard of `CSS` and went through some tutorials & did self practice but i feel something missing and don't feel much confidence when i see other coding standard.

Pls suggest me some good tutorials/ share your experience to enhance my skill. I am fade up of reading online tutorials.

Comment: Read some web design blogs like http://www.smashingmagazine.com/, http://www.alistapart.com/ etc. They generally have small tutorials on specific sections which will help you out as you start. Occasionally http://sixrevisions.com/ has good tutorials on building a website from mockup too.

Comment: [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) is good to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice would be to start coding yourself. Just start building web applications and learn as you go; you can get stuck looking for the best tutorials.

With that said, if you haven't stumbled on this yet, http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/ is the best tutorial in my opinion.

Comment: indeed ... [Beginner](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/), [Intermediate](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/), and [Advanced](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/) tutorials on HTML Dog

Comment: thanks phil :) i am so much glad to read this tutorial, also very surprised that how didn't i find this earlier. Anyway many thanks to you & all who answered.

Answer (score 1):

A List Apart is great... read the css articles form the bottom up: http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/

Also i know some people cant grok it and its horribly technical and you have to kind of learn the language but i cant stress enough how much better off youll be if you actually take the time to read and understand the technical definition of CSS an how it works. A lot of things happen form misunderstanding box model and how things lay out, and then how it differences in standards complaint browsers and non-compliant browsers.

- CSS 2.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/
- CSS 3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/

Answer (score 0):

I've recently watched the PluralSight movies and it was amazing if you looking for a movie tutorial. I know you have to pay to watch it, but first day that it released it was free to watch! 
http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=css-intro